# Sequelize associations model queryies

Tags: javascript, express, associations, sequelize.js

i am trying to do a simple `findAll` operation on my `Statue` table. However the `findAll` operation also looks through all associated models as well, which is NOT my intended behavior.

My statue association model is set up like,

```
statue.associate = function(models) {
  const { comment, image, like } = models;

  statue.hasMany(comment, {
    foreignKey: 'model_id',
    constraints: false,
    scope: {
      model_name: 'statue'
    }
  });

  statue.hasMany(image, {
    foreignKey: 'model_id',
    constraints: false,
    scope: {
      model_name: 'statue'
    }
  });

  statue.hasMany(like, {
    foreignKey: 'model_id',
    constraints: false,
    scope: {
      model_name: 'statue'
    }
  });
};
```

When i run:

```
const statues = await Statue.findAll();
```

I get back the statue object i want and see this postgres command line output as intended.

```
SELECT "id", "title", "artist_desc", "artist_name", "artist_url", "statue_desc", "location", "created_at", "updated_at" FROM "statues" AS "statue";
```

But i also see,

```
SELECT "id", "user_id", "text", "model_name", "model_id", "created_at", "updated_at" FROM "comments" AS "comment" WHERE "comment"."model_name" = 'statue' AND "comment"."model_id" = 1;
SELECT "id", "model_name", "model_id", "url", "height", "width", "created_at", "updated_at" FROM "images" AS "image" WHERE "image"."model_name" = 'statue' AND "image"."model_id" = 1;
SELECT "id", "user_id", "model_name", "model_id", "created_at", "updated_at" FROM "likes" AS "like" WHERE "like"."model_name" = 'statue' AND "like"."model_id" = 1;
```

which are the related models, but then the output i receive with

```
return res.json(statues);
```

is `{}`.

Any direction would be extremely helpful. I am extremely new to postgres & express.

To add, i do want all of these associated models in the returning response, but currently even the statue model response is being swallowed up...

Answer (score 0):

To include the related models, you can use [eager loading](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#eager-loading)

```
const statues = await Statue.findAll({include: [image]});
```

You can also include all the associated models without specifying them individually

```
Statue.findAll({ include: [{ all: true }]});
```

From the output perspective, please log the value of `statues` and also check the if you have values in DB.